# AWS Lambda testing from console throws missing access token

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a aws lambda function to read an object from bucket 1 and upload the object to bucket 2.
I have set trigger in bucket 1 to the lambda function for any object created.

The role associated to lambda execution has the following access
[image: permissions]

the code of my lambda funtion is

```
@Override
public String handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {
    try {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        System.out.println("started!");
        InputStream objectData = null;
        String s = "";

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("abc","efg");
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);


        for (S3EventNotificationRecord record : input.getRecords()) {
            String s3Key = record.getS3().getObject().getKey();


            String s3Bucket = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
            context.getLogger().log("found id: " + s3Bucket + " " + s3Key);

            // retrieve s3 object added
            S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                    s3Bucket, s3Key));
            objectData = object.getObjectContent();

            context.getLogger().log(objectData.toString());


            TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3Client);
            ObjectMetadata s3ObjectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            s3ObjectMetadata.setContentLength(object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength());
            s3ObjectMetadata.setContentType(object.getObjectMetadata()
                    .getContentType());
            transferManager.upload("bucket2", s3Key, objectData,
                    s3ObjectMetadata);
        }
        return objectData.toString();
```

when i try to execute the lambda fucntion from aws console, it throws up missing access token error. The lambda is uploaded to bucket1. Please help me with what am missing in the config/code.

Comment: Which line gives you the error? It could be that you need to pass a `AmazonS3Config` to the `AmazonS3Client` constructor

Comment: My lambda is not having any problem in execution when i try it using eclipse plugin.

Comment: Does the role that you use have a statement in it's trust policy with a principal lambda.amazonaws.com? That would to me explain how it might work from your eclipse plugin and not in aws console. The lambda service needs trust to assume the role. I assume the eclipse plugin just runs code locally with w/e iam you have configured.

Comment: Hi @defond, it has the trust policy associated with the role.
*Trusted Entities
The following trusted entities can assume this role.
Trusted Entities
The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com*

Comment: hmmm, thought maybe that was it. Sorry that didn't get it.